# Is it more performant to transform arrays into objects and then manipulating with objects instead of arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a web developer mostly using ReactJs and so far whenever I had a "list" of data I stored them in an array, but every time I had to modify or delete an item of the array I had to do like `.filter()` or `.map()` which normally goes through all the list and it's really unnecessary if I am removing or modifying just an item so I thought of using Objects,
if I get some data like:

```
  [
    { id: 1, name: "Tony" },
    { id: 2, name: "Toad" },
    { id: 3, name: "Gon" }
  ];
```

I turn it into an object like:

```
const object = {};
  [
    { id: 1, name: "Tony" },
    { id: 2, name: "Toad" },
    { id: 3, name: "Gon" }
  ].forEach((item) => (object[item.id] = item));
```

And since the id I know that will always be unique when I have to delete an element  I can just say `delete object["some key"]`, or if I have to modify I can say `object["some key"]= modifiedItem`. I've worked only on few projects done by other people but never really saw someone going like this. I am wondering is it worth to go this approach?

There is one downside to this that I can think of, if I want to render the items I would have to do `Object.keys(object).map(key=>(<div>{object[key].name}</div>))` as if it was an array I would just have to do `array.map(item=>(<div>{item.name}</div>))` So having to reconsider this, is it worth to turn the array into an object or sticking with arrays?

Comment: Relevant: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2):

No, not a good idea for a few reasons:

1. React relies on new references to objects (arrays, pojos, etc.) in order to know that a change has been made and that the DOM should update. Using `delete` on an object does not change its reference. Of course, you can be vigilant to avoid errors like these, but it's a most likely not a good idea because of reason 2.
2. Don't perform optimizations that make the code harder to reason about unless a performance problem has actually come up. The modern computer is extremely fast. You do not need to make the same performance considerations that programmers made 50 years ago. Does your array have tens of thousands of entries or thousands of entries, where entry in the array is an immensely complex object? If so, then I'd be happy to talk about various performance strategies.

If you have *actually* run into such severe issues, the solution is always context-dependent. What is slow about it? How much HTML are you rendering per entry in your `Array#map` operation? How often does the array need to be updated (aka state being triggered)? What is the most common array manipulation you end up using? How often are you updating the HTML?

- Large HTML: Your real enemy is React's reconciliation algorithm/Virtual DOM. Pull out the HTML inside each `map` into a separate component. Design the component in a way where you can suppress propagating rerenders from the parent.
- Virtualize (less HTML on the page) or paginate (smaller array to manipulate) your list. There's no silver bullet to avoid array manipulation. The best thing you can do is change the size of the array you are continually working with or change the amount of HTML that is getting rendered.

The slowest part of the browser is the DOM. Never forget that. In an overwhelming majority of situations, algorithms are chump change in comparison

Comment: *Don't perform optimizations that make the code harder to reason about unless a performance problem has actually come up* This is key.

Comment: I don't really see it going that large or having some very complex objects, although would like to know the strategies you would go for if that was the case

Comment: @Alfred the problem is that the strategy to deal with a performance problem will depend on what is slow. The basic strategy is trading CPU time for memory by using a lookup table like you suggested in the question. But if `.filter()` is slow for you, I doubt making the object on the fly in order to delete one item then converting the object back into an array will be *faster*. You've traded one `O(n)` loop for two - `O(n)` and `O(n-1)`. You should probably keep the lookup live at all times. But that's not always the best strategy, either.

Answer (score 0):

I see your point, I've actually done the same a couple of times, but I'd say it depends on the case. In most cases, you'd rather keep the array.

Think about all of the higher-order array methods, each of them fulfills a specific purpose, like `filter`, `find`, `some`, or even the more complex ones like `reduce`. Usually, you'll manipulate a list of data quite a bit in frontend development

Comment: maybe I'll have to wait and see if the data will get too large and do users update those data frequently, in that case maybe will be more worthy to do it? Because finding data would  always be O(1) since I will always have the id of the item I wanna operate on but not the index of it's position in array, that's why I was thinking of this conversion, and as you mentioned  I will have to think if other array methods will be used on those data if not now also not in the future

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript objects(which are hash), this is the time complexity of the operations you want to perform:

- Modification = O(1)
- Deletion = Amortized O(1) meaning it will be  constant for most
  cases, but not necessarily all of them.

For arrays, since you are storing objects inside them as elements, you will have to filter them through traversal since you can't access them by index, which means your time complexity is:

- Modification - O(n)
- Deletion - O(n) may be O(n2) if you use splice for deletion

On the other hand:

```
 array.map(item=>(<div>{item.name}</div>))
```

This will run a single loop so O(n)

As for this:

```
Object.keys(object).map(key=>(<div>{object[key].name}</div>))
```

This will be O(n2), one loop for Object.keys() and one for map(), which is still o(n)

So in conclusion, If you regularly need to modify, access or delete objects based on the id, stick with objects.

But for cases where you only need to render the list of objects or delete infrequently, stick with arrays.

Side note: Unless you frequently delete or modify these objects, stick with arrays. From a performance perspective, it is negligible if you only trigger these operations a few times.

Comment: The entire purpose has been defeated. The original goal was to avoid an O(n) operation for deletion. `Object.keys` has the same time complexity as `Array#filter`. Any performance differences between the two would be compiler dependent and almost certainly trivial

Comment: I've made a small correction, deletion is O(1) amortized in objects, also you're right, it's negligible from a performance perspective, but that also depends on how frequently the questioner will delete or modify.